# Android AsyncTask Fragment Loading

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm attempting to create an a JSON-populated listview in an Android fragment.  The app crashes in the AsyncTask area but I'm not sure what the issue is.  I'm trying to go by an original tutorial that used an activity but I'm converting it to a fragment:  http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13239/android-mysql-php-json-part-6-json-parsing-and-android-design/ ;  Will gladly post the whole fragment code if needed.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Fragment as a whole:

```
public class mainViewController extends ListFragment
{

    Context context;

    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // testing on Emulator:
        private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "https://MY_URL";


        // JSON IDS:
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
        private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final String TAG_POST_ID = "post_id";
        private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
        // it's important to note that the message is both in the parent branch of
        // our JSON tree that displays a "Post Available" or a "No Post Available"
        // message,
        // and there is also a message for each individual post, listed under the
        // "posts"
        // category, that displays what the user typed as their message.

        // An array of all of our comments
        private JSONArray mComments = null;
        // manages all of our comments in a list.
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    public mainViewController()
    {
    }

    String[] mainFeed = {};

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
//                  inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
//                  mainFeed);
//
//          setListAdapter(adapter);


         return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            // loading the comments via AsyncTask
            new LoadComments().execute();
        }

        public void addComment(View v) {
//          Intent i = new Intent(ReadComments.this, AddComment.class);
//          startActivity(i);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
         */
        public void updateJSONdata() {

            // Instantiate the arraylist to contain all the JSON data.
            // we are going to use a bunch of key-value pairs, referring
            // to the json element name, and the content, for example,
            // message it the tag, and "I'm awesome" as the content..

            mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Bro, it's time to power up the J parser
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Feed the beast our comments url, and it spits us
            // back a JSON object. Boo-yeah Jerome.
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

            // when parsing JSON stuff, we should probably
            // try to catch any exceptions:
            try {

                // I know I said we would check if "Posts were Avail." (success==1)
                // before we tried to read the individual posts, but I lied...
                // mComments will tell us how many "posts" or comments are
                // available
                mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

                // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
                for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                    // gets the content of each tag
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String content = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, content);
                    map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    mCommentList.add(map);

                    // annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with our array
                    // list
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
         */
        private void updateList() {
            // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to do
            //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
            //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
            //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
            //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
            //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.context, mCommentList,
                    R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_MESSAGE,
                            TAG_USERNAME }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
                            R.id.username });

            // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we 
            //could do something.  However, we will choose
            //to do nothing...
            ListView lv = getListView();    
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // This method is triggered if an item is click within our
                    // list. For our example we won't be using this, but
                    // it is useful to know in real life applications.

                }
            });
        }


        public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
//              pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainViewController.this);
//              pDialog.setMessage("Loading Posts...");
//              pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//              pDialog.setCancelable(true);
//              pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                updateJSONdata();
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //pDialog.dismiss();
                updateList();
            }
        }

     @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        }
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
//              pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainViewController.this);
//              pDialog.setMessage("Loading Posts...");
//              pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//              pDialog.setCancelable(true);
//              pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                updateJSONdata();
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //pDialog.dismiss();
                updateList();
            }
        }

     @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        }
}
```

Android Error:

08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819): Process: com.rynovation.kline, PID: 22819
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.(SimpleAdapter.java:85)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController.updateList(mainViewController.java:159)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController.access$0(mainViewController.java:152)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController$LoadComments.onPostExecute(mainViewController.java:209)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController$LoadComments.onPostExecute(mainViewController.java:1)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-04 22:14:53.530: E/AndroidRuntime(22819):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, your `updateList` method is instantiating a SimpleAdapter, and that's where the `NullPointerException` is being thrown. You should include the `updateList` code as well.

Comment: Ok, one sec.  I'll post the whole Fragment.

Comment: yes you can because you do not consume the result you could change AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> to AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> and just return and also change  super.onPostExecute(result); to  super.onPostExecute();

Comment: set breakpoint at  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.context, mCommentList, ... and check if any of them is null ?

Comment: I'm just getting a null pointer exception.  Doesn't say anything specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context you're passing in is null, since nowhere in your code is `this.context` set. Use [`Fragment.getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()]) instead.

Comment: Where at?  I tried setting Fragment.getActivity in place of the context here: ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.Fragment.getActivity(), mCommentList, ; and it would not let me.

Comment: try this mainViewController.this.getActivity()

Comment: No such luck anywhere in the code.  I tried adding it at the top of the class.